# Struts2 - html:img tag alternative

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts1

What is the equivalent in struts2 for **html:img** tag?

```
<html:img page="/img/test.gif" border="0" alt="Test"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't equivalent in Struts 2 you should use ordinary HTML `<img>` tag but with the help of [`<s:url>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/url-tag.html).

```xml
<s:url var="url" value="/img/test.gif"/>
<img src="${url}" border="0" alt="Test">
```